# Using jquery mobile for developing windows phone 8 app

Tags: jquery-mobile, windows-8, cordova

The UI look and feel provided by jQuery Mobile closely follows iPhone. Currently I'm creating a windows 8 mobile application using Apache's Cordova. Can I use jQuery Mobile for the UI along with this metro style-sheet (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2012/04/26/more-news-from-ms-open-tech-announcing-the-open-source-metro-style-theme.aspx)?

Is jQueryMobile is created to use only for mobile websites not for web apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been looking for a while for cross platform tools to build native-looking and feeling apps. The best I could find is Chui http://www.chocolatechip-ui.com/

It includes his own DOM manipulation and paging system, very similar to jQuery, and three CSS stylesheets (android, ios, wp8) which are very native-looking.

You can still use jQuery and only apply the CSS sheets. Really worth giving it a try.

BTW, jQuery mobile doesn't really look like iphone (not IOS7 at all). What is nice about jQuery mobile is that it creates his own controls (menu bar, slide bar, buttons...) but they don't look like native. Chui does the same, and looks native. Really.

Another downside to jQuery mobile, it slows down the performance. It is still a cool solution if you already know jQuery, but as I did you'll gladly move to something else afterwards.

And yes you can use jQuery mobile for web apps. I assume you are talking about phonegap - once in the webview, you can use anything as if you were in a browser.

Now I am not saying that Chui is the best thing around, I've been using it for only a few days, but between all the frameworks and libraries I tried, it's the most native-looking by far, on any of the three platforms.